# JEE6 : Alternative EJB declaration

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, jboss7.x, cdi

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 with CDI.

I've got a Stateless bean named ServiceAccount in JNDI. This is the real service implementation.
I've got another Statelss bean named ServiceAccountMock which is a Mock service.
The both herited from the same interface and are packaged in a service.ear.

What I want to do is to declare the mock service as alternative in bean.xml, redeploy my services ear, and then all the client see the mock version (without changing anything on client side).

When I deploy my service.ear, JBoss says :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011046: A component named 'ServiceAccount' is already defined in this module
```

This is true, both services are declared the same way (@Stateless(name="ServiceAccount")).

If I change the name of the mock version, I have to change on client side which EJB is used (and I don't want to do that).

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Does the deployment error go away when you specify a different name in the @Stateless annotation, for the alternative stateless EJB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to deploy 2 beans with the same name in the same application.

If the clients of the bean are only local, you should use CDI type injection selection.

- Remove the name of the beans or put different name if you realy need a name (The mock will have a different name that the real implementation).
- Keep the `@Alternative` annotation on the mock.
- At the injection point, use the interface as the type of variable (and probably using the `@Inject` annotation instead of the `@EJB` one may help).

The EJB specification and CDI aren't yet completly aligned.  EJB has some element like the name that need to be unique over the application and is not taken into account in the CDI alternative functionaltity.

So I don't think you will be able to mix EJB name injection selection and CDI alternative injection selection.

Comment: That is also my conclusion. The workaround I implement was to have a unique EJB facade in which is injected a different implementation with CDI : for the client EJB is always the same and I can transparently route the call to other mock beans.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to annotate `ServiceAccountMock` with `@Alternative`, to tell the container not to use it if not instructed to.

```
@Stateless(name="ServiceAccount")
@Alternative
public class ServiceAccountMock{
....
}
```

Then in `beans.xml` you need to tell the A/S to pick the mock implementation:

```
...
<alternatives>
    <class>xx.yy.ServiceAccountMock</class>
</alternatives>
...
```

Comment: @jmcollin92 In that case, I think a little code should help. In particular the class signatures of `ServiceAccount` and `ServiceAccountMock`

Comment: Thx for your answer. Like Kazaag above, I think it is not really possible. CDI don't deals with JNDI : @Alternative don't modify the JNDI. I've posted above a workaround for people which could be interested.